# Pandas: group by two columns or more

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
item_id | item_count | day | month
   1    |     2      |  1  |   1
   2    |     1      |  1  |   2
...
```

The dataframe tells what is the `item_id` and how many it is sold `item_count` per `day`, and in which `month`. I want to get the `item_count` of every `item_id` per `month`. I think I have to groupby both `item_id` and `month`, but which of the first seems to give the wrong result. How do I do that?

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['item_id','month'], as_index=False)['tem_count'].sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used groupby but i am getting the result that you seem to be expecting - here is what i have done.

```
df.groupby(['item_id ',' month']).sum()
```

is this what you were looking for ?